# .NET application crashing on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: .net-3.5, 64-bit, badimageformatexception

I have made an application and made the setup installer using Visual Studio 2010 and [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework 3.5.

In Visual Studio 2010 I have selected "Any CPU" as platform, so it can run on both 64-bit and 32-bit Windows 7 OSes.

When I am installing it on Windows 7 64-bit, it gets installed successfully, but when I tried to open the application it is giving me the following dump:

> Description:   Stopped working
>
> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3   Problem
>   Signature 01:    elanguidescd.mediaplayer.exe   Problem Signature 02: 
>   1.0.0.0   Problem Signature 03:    4e295e12   Problem Signature 04:
>   System.Windows.Forms   Problem Signature 05:    2.0.0.0   Problem
>   Signature 06:    4d8c1991   Problem Signature 07:    19bb   Problem
>   Signature 08:    1a   Problem Signature 09:
>   System.BadImageFormatException   OS Version:    6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
>   Locale ID:    1033
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our 
>     privacy statement offline: C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Answer (score 3):

[`System.BadImageFormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) means that you tried to reference a 32-bit dll from a 64-bit assembly (or the other way around). You can't mix and match stuff like this. If you need to reference 32-bit dll's, make you application 32-bit, not "Any CPU".